# Problem based on Poisson distribution

Tags: limits, poisson-distribution, probability-limit-theorems

It is required to obtain the following:

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}e^{-n}\sum_{j=n}^{4n}\frac{n^j}{j!}$

The only thing that I understand here is that the expression inside the limit is a pmf of Poisson distribution but not able to calculate this.

I made a substitution $x=j-n$ also but that didn't work either.

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X_n$ have Poisson distribution with parameter $n$. Let $Y_n=\frac {X_n -n} {\sqrt n}$. It is known that $Y_n$ converges to standard normal distribution. The given probability is $P\{n \leq X_n \leq 4n\} =P\{0 \leq Y_n \leq 3\sqrt n\}$ so the limit is $\frac 1 2$.

Comment: I understood till $P(0\leq Y_{n}\leq3\sqrt{n})$. You used idea of central limit theorem. It is going to be $\Phi{(3\sqrt{n})}$. But, how will this limit be $\frac{1}{2}$. One more thing that when applying central limit theorem in Discrete Distribution, I had studied that we need to apply continuity correction but you have not used it.

Comment: See https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=2ahUKEwj5voHv0e_aAhUBO48KHbzbD_IQFjADegQIABBR&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcourses.wcupa.edu%2Frbove%2FBerenson%2F10th%2520ed%2520CD-ROM%2520topics%2Fsection6_5.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0Ed82xT895i8MINaSgmnBP for normal approximation to Poisson. When you take limit as $n \to \infty$ how can the limit still depend on $n$?. What you get is $P\{0\leq Z <\infty\}$ where $Z$ is standard normal and this probability is 1/2.