# Evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty} \exp(-n^2) \sum_{j=n}^{4n} \frac{n^j}{j! }$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

> Question : Evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty} \exp(-n^2) \sum_{j=n}^{4n} \frac{n^j}{j! }$.

We can not separate the limits here as there are chances of the resultant to be some indeterminate. Let $a_n=\sum_{j=n}^{4n}\frac{n^j}{j!}$ (a) , on expanding we have $a_n=\frac{n^n}{n!}+\frac{n^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}+\frac{n^{n+2}}{(n+2)!}+\dots+\frac{n^{4n}}{(4n)!}$ (this is not a gp). I know that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}=\exp(x)$. Using it here didn't made any sense to me. How about using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation, but didn't simplified.
Taking $\log$ on both sides of (a) we have $\log a_n=\sum_{j=n}^{4n}\log \frac{n^j}{j!}$,this will include another sum (not easy  for "ME" to handle).

Thanks.

Comment: I am not aware of poisson distribution @MartinR.

Comment: @MartinR OP has $e^{-n^{2}}$.

Comment: @geetha290krm: From the similarity with https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2767283/42969 and the possible answers ($1/6,1/4,1/2,3/4$), I would assume a typo in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sum_{j=n}^{4n} \frac{n^j}{j! }\leq \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^j}{j! }=e^{n}$ and $e^{-n^{2}+n} \to 0$

Comment: This is a Multiple choice question and available answers are $1/6 , 1/4,1/2,3/4$.

Comment: None of those is correct. But if you have $e^{-n}$ instead of $e^{-n^{2}}$ then the answer is $\frac  1 2$. Either there is a typo in the question or you have copied the question wrongly. @AasthaChoudhary

Comment: A typo could be an issue. Thanks.